# How to support multiple endpoints with Dagger 2.0 while using MockWebServer

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, okhttp, mockwebserver

For an Android project I configured Retrofit 2.1.0 and OkHttp 3.4.1 with Dagger 2.6 as shown in the following Dagger module. I am aiming to support multiple backends using `@Named` qualifiers.

```
@Module
public class ApiModule {

    private static final String GITHUB_QUALIFIER = "GitHub";

    private static final String TWITTER_QUALIFIER = "Twitter";

    @Provides
    GitHubClient provideGitHubClient(@Named(GITHUB_QUALIFIER) Retrofit retrofit) { /* ... */ }

    @Provides
    TwitterClient provideTwitterClient(@Named(TWITTER_QUALIFIER) Retrofit retrofit) { /* ... */ }

    @Named(GITHUB_QUALIFIER)
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    HttpUrl provideGitHubBaseUrl() { /* ... */ }

    @Named(TWITTER_QUALIFIER)
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    HttpUrl provideTwitterBaseUrl() { /* ... */ }

    @Named(GITHUB_QUALIFIER)
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit getGitHubRetrofit(@Named(GITHUB_QUALIFIER) HttpUrl httpUrl, 
                               OkHttpClient okHttpClient) { /* ... */ }

    @Named(TWITTER_QUALIFIER)
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit getTwitterRetrofit(@Named(TWITTER_QUALIFIER) HttpUrl httpUrl, 
                                OkHttpClient okHttpClient) { /* ... */ }

    private Retrofit getRetrofit(String baseUrl, 
                                 OkHttpClient okHttpClient) { /* ... */ }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient() { /* ... */ }

}
```

I want to use [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) for testing. However, I cannot find out how I can pass in the URL of the MockWebServer while at the same time supporting multiple backends:

```
// From a unit test

mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
mockWebServer.start();
ApiModule apiModule = new ApiModule();
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

String url = mockWebServer.url("/").toString();
// Here I cannot pass the URL to Retrofit
Retrofit retrofit = apiModule.provideRetrofit(/* HERE */ okHttpClient);

gitHubClient = apiModule.provideGitHubClient(retrofit);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to override base url with okhttp interceptor.

```
public final class HostSelectionInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private volatile String mHost;

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.mHost = checkNotNull(host);
    }

    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        String host = this.mHost;
        if (host != null) {
            HttpUrl overriddenBaseUrl = HttpUrl.parse(host);
            HttpUrl newUrl = request.url()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .host(overriddenBaseUrl.host())
                    .build();
            request = request.newBuilder()
                    .url(newUrl)
                    .build();
        }
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

Taken from here: https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/8571a8207a5815cca1fb

You can use this interceptor to feed MockWebServer url or even switch between staging endpoints for debug builds.